# How to embed audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio, soundcloud

I'm trying to design a surveymonkey survey that has some audio embedded in it.  As in people taking the survey can listen to an audio clip, and answer questions about it.

How to best get it done, I'm not entirely sure.  In surveymonkey, you can embed little self-contained HTML scripts into your questions (think like the "HTML widget" on blogger).

I'm thinking I can do all this via HTML, Javascript and SoundCloud.  As in keep the audio on soundcloud and create a buttons that plays the particular audio file.

So I'll be good as long as I end with something to the tune of a `<button type="button" onclick="playClip()">Play</button>`

BUT!  What's everyone's take...how should the theoretical Javascript function "playClip" look, so that it just plays the soundcloud file?

(PS - I don't want to just drop in the URL from soundcloud.  It makes that big messy player, and I'd like to use quite a few of these audio clips and if I just past half a dozen urls in there, its going to loose a lot of the usability)

help me obi-wan kenobi!

Comment: Did you look at the API?: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#resolving

Answer (score 0):

```
function playClip(url){
  if(playClip.aud)playClip.aud.pause(); //stop previous track, if any
  (playClip.aud=new Audio(url)).play(); //load and play url
}


playClip("https://ec-media.soundcloud.com/jhfLh2n9tyEY.128.mp3?ff61182e3c2ecefa438cd02102d0e385713f0c1faf3b0339595665fc0701eb1c8ae8afa5c1059e14eaaf9e74d90a7660706e6a2265abbac2c25c5fcd0f2f1f7fbcfd70b793&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4IAZE5EOI7PA7VQ&Expires=1366840864&Signature=LmZu8Sgq2k8mfI8ivHGZGqQEj3k%3D");
```